# Deploying Identity Server4 on ECS

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to migrate identity server4 running on ec2 machine to ecs.Identity server working fine when deployed it on IIS server on ec2 machin but it is throwing 404 error when deployed it on ecs and task is running for some time and stopping with the following error.

Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint ecs-IIS-identityserver-task-20-IIS-identityserver-task-c897d89a99eecc9db201 on network nat: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The specified port alre

when checked it there is not other applications running with the port on ecs.Not sure what is causing the issue.